# [IntelliJ 20202.2]: Does git pull --rebase via the new dialog preserve merge commits?

Tags: intellij-idea

The new pull dialog offers `--rebase` as an option. I´d like to know, if it´s recreating the merge commits, i.e. if it does a `pull --rebase-merges`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fetching the changes from a remote branch, IntelliJ IDEA will rebase them onto the current branch instead of merging them. So IDE doesn't run `--rebase-merges.`

Please see for more:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sync-with-a-remote-repository.html#pull